# Dynamically created jQuery selectors with eval?

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, onclick, eval

I'm trying to dynamically bind click listeners to divs in a for loop.

If the second jQuery selector doesn't have `+ i`, but is hard coded, then it works, like so:

```
eval(jQuery('#patient_name' + i).on('click touchstart', function(){jQuery('#taskstat0').slideToggle();}));
```

I also tried using two evals in the line like this:

```
eval(jQuery('#patient_name' + i)).on('click touchstart', function(){eval(jQuery('#taskstat' + i)).slideToggle();});
```

Yet this fails without console errors:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var patient_count = jQuery('.patient_dropdown').length;
    for(var i=0; i<patient_count; i++){
        eval(jQuery('#patient_name' + i).on('click touchstart', function(){jQuery('#taskstat0').slideToggle();}));
    }
});
```

I expect each `#patient_namex` to show the corresponding `#taskstatx` div underneath when clicked.

What can be done to make it work?

Comment: You don't need eval.  Your root issue is the scope of the `i`.  You need to use a closure.

Comment: Thank you @Taplar for pointing it out!

Comment: Use something like `jQuery('.patient_dropdown').on('click touchstart', function () { $(this).next().slideToggle(); });` or another way of selecting the appropriate element based on the clicked one.